# Ethernet won't work on a Pi 2 - Model B V1.1 running latest Raspbian

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I have tried both raspbian stretch lite as well as desktop edition and ethernet does not work on this model. I have updated the firmware on the pi. All the software updates are installed. I have tested the cable, the switch as well as DHCP Server.

I tried plugging in a USB - Ethernet Dongle and it works fine with the same cable and switch.

```
$uname -a
4.19.34-v7+ #1211 SMP Mon Apr 8 22:56:37 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

```
$ethtool -i eth0
driver: smsc95xx
version: 22-Aug-2005
firmware-version: smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: usb-3f980000.usb-1.1
supports-statistics: no
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000 
     link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 
      inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo 
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
      inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 

2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000 
     link/ether b8:27:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I have also tried updating the /boot/cmdline.txt and /etc/sysctl.conf as suggested on some sites, that didn't help either.

Additional Notes: The same pi used to work with older version of raspbian.

Comment: What is your network configuration? `ip a`

Comment: ```$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: You should add that information to the question. It is better visible and you can format it properly. The driver seems to think that your Ethernet cable is not connected.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying a previous version again, just to make sure.  The versions can be found here:
http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/

Answer (score 0):

You are using an experimental kernel and presumably firmware, probably from running `rpi-update`. There are outstanding issues with the 4.19 kernel.

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911
>   Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel`
will put it back to the latest supported kernel/bootcode.

Comment: Thanks! I did rpi-update just in an attempt to fix this issue. 
I did downgrade the bootloader and the kernel, but that didn't help either.


$ uname -a
Linux pi2 4.14.98-v7+ #1200 SMP Tue Feb 12 20:27:48 GMT 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux